# Changing variable scope in SSIS programatically

Tags: c#, ssis

Is there a way to change a variable scope in SSIS programatically?

for example, this variable will be created on the package level:

```
package.Variables.Add("sSourceObjectId", false, "User", 1);
```

But I need to create the variable on the OnError scope, because the system variable ErrorCode is not visible to the package level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to access the Variables collection on the specific Task/Container

The following code creates an SSIS package that has an OnError event handler at the package level. On that event handler, `eh`, I add the variable `sSourceObjectId`

```
string path = @"C:\ssisdata\p1.dtsx";

Application app = new Application();
Package pkg = new Package();
pkg.Name = "so_29925774";
DtsEventHandler eh = pkg.EventHandlers.Add("OnError") as DtsEventHandler;

eh.Variables.Add("sSourceObjectId", false, "User", 1);

app.SaveToXml(path, pkg, null);
```

### Resulting package

You can see that the Variable is scoped to the OnError event and not the package itself.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, billinkc! Works as expected.